# Integrate Admin LTE with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, adminlte

How to integrate/embed Admin LTE with laravel 5.2. I have found tutorials but can't get..Can anyone tell the procedure step by step. I have installed the latest laravel version which is 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

At first ensure that *nodejs* and *git* is installed on your system.

After that go inside the folder where you have installed laravel

then you need to Install Bower by

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then install AdminLte by

```
bower install admin-lte
```

You can also follow the link here

https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel

Answer (score 1):

You can use Acacha AdminLTE Laravel package:

https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel

```
composer global require "acacha/adminlte-laravel-installer=~3.0"
```

And convert any Laravel projectto AdminLTE/Pratt with:

```
laravel new laravel-with-admin-lte
cd laravel-with-admin-lte
adminlte-laravel install
```

And Enjoy! If you wish you can use llum:

```
llum boot
```

To quickly start your project in your favourite web browser!